# Django. Heroku. Delete migrations on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I want to add a couple of new fields to my app in Heroku. I wouldn't like to lose the data I have there. So, I tried using South but it kept giving me errors, it looks like I made a mistake somewhere and now I need to delete the migrations and try again. In a local environment this is done by deleting the migrations folder and dropping the south_migrationhistory tables. I am new to Heroku, I guess the commands are similar, but I can't seem to find them. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku comes with the ability to run a unix shell remotely, it works pretty much like `ssh`.

Just type `heroku run bash` in a terminal (from the git repo of your project of course), and you will end up with a bash prompt that can be used to explore the file system and process environment of your project, including South migration files.

Hope this helps.